# Node.js module.exports passport isAuthenticated to routes

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, routes, passport-local

I wanted to separate each group of routes in a file. I need to use isAuthenticated in most routes to restrict access. When I put all routes in the same file it works.

When I use `module.exports = isAuthenticated` in auth.js and in order.js I use `var auth = require('auth.js');` I will get a error of 'isAuthenticated is not defined' when I go to http://localhost:3000/order the routes defined in auth.js just works as expected.

I'm using Express.js middleware 'Passport local strategy' (followed tutorial from tutsplus and downloaded github repository from [here](https://github.com/tutsplus/passport-mongo)).

My project structure:

```
bin/www
models/auth/init.js
models/auth/user.js
models/auth/signup.js
models/auth/login.js
models/order.js
views/error.pug
views/index.pug
views/home.pug
views/layout.pug
views/order.pug
views/register.pug
routes/order.js 
routes/auth.js
public/stylesheets/style.css
app.js
db.js
```

./routes/auth.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    // if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler 
    // Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
    // request and response objects
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    // if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
    res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = isAuthenticated;

module.exports = function(passport){

    /* GET login page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
        res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message') });
    });

    /* Handle Login POST */
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash : true  
    }));

    /* GET Registration Page */
    router.get('/signup', function(req, res){
        res.render('register',{message: req.flash('message')});
    });

    /* Handle Registration POST */
    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/signup',
        failureFlash : true  
    }));

    /* GET Home Page */
    router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        res.render('home', { user: req.user });
    });


    /* Handle Logout */
    router.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    return router;
}
```

./routes/order.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var order = require('../models/order');

var auth = require('./auth.js');



module.exports = function(passport){

    router.get('/order', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('order');

    });

    router.post('/order', isAuthenticated, function(req, res)
    {
        var testorder = new order({
            orderid: '52363',
            productname: 'it works',
            quantity: 1337
        });
        testorder.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {console.log(err.stack);}    
            console.log('saving done...');
        });

            res.render('order', { product: req.body.productname });
    });

};
```

./app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var pug = require('pug');

var dbConfig = require('./db');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url);

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Configuring Passport
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
// TODO - Why Do we need this key ?
app.use(expressSession({secret: 'mySecretKey'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

 // Using the flash middleware provided by connect-flash to store messages in session
 // and displaying in templates
var flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());

// Initialize Passport
var initPassport = require('./models/auth/init.js');
initPassport(passport);

var auth = require('./routes/auth')(passport);
var order = require('./routes/order');
app.use('/', auth);
app.use('/order', order);
/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try auth.isAuntheticated(),
It should work that way.

Comment: I changed it in router.get('/order', auth.isAuthenticated, function(req, res){ .... } in order.js I get this stack trace: https://pastebin.com/d8z15Afz

Comment: Try auth.isAuthenticated()

Comment: Error: auth.isAuthenticated is not a function

Comment: Your  code seems not to be well structured,try and structure it properly.Meanwhile to solve you problem quickly,copy isAuthenticated function and paste it anywhere you need the middleware.Then this should work     router.post('/order', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){...})